# Excel VBA Custom Sort

Tags: excel, vba

I have the `E3:E300` range with numbers. I want to use a custom sort for it:

1 to 50, then 701 to 720, then 51 to the remaining numbers.

```
With ActiveSheet.Sort
  .SetRange Range("A3:AA300")
  .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E3"), Order1:=xlAscending  
  .Header = xlYes
  .Apply
End With
```

How to do that?

Comment: Is using a helper column an option?

Comment: @FunThomas yes if its unavoidable

Comment: I don't think there is a custom sort function in Excel except defining lookup lists, but I don't think you want to enter an entry for every possible value, so that's not an option. I think the best bet is to create a helper column with a formula like `=E3+IF(AND(E3>51,E3<700),1000,0)` and sort by that column

Comment: Is column ˙`AB` empty?

Comment: @VBasic2008 column X is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by formula:

```vb
=LET(data,A2:C301,idxSortColumn,3,
sortColumn,CHOOSECOLS(data,idxSortColumn),
sort1,SORT(FILTER(data,sortColumn<=50),idxSortColumn),
sort2, SORT(FILTER(data,(sortColumn>=701)*(sortColumn<=720)),idxSortColumn),
sort3,SORT(FILTER(data,((sortColumn>50)*(sortColumn<701))),idxSortColumn),
VSTACK(sort1,sort2,sort3))
```

Adjust `data` and `idxSortColumn` to your needs.

You could use this formula in VBA to insert the sorted array and then paste the result to the source range.

```vb
Sub sort()

Dim rgSort As Range
Set rgSort = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:C301")

Dim sortFormula As String
sortFormula = "=LET(data," & rgSort.Address & ",idxSortColumn,3," & vbLf & _
    "sortColumn,CHOOSECOLS(data,idxSortColumn)," & vbLf & _
    "sort1,SORT(FILTER(data,sortColumn<=50),idxSortColumn)," & vbLf & _
    "sort2, SORT(FILTER(data,(sortColumn>=701)*(sortColumn<=720)),idxSortColumn)," & vbLf & _
    "sort3,SORT(FILTER(data,((sortColumn>50)*(sortColumn<701))),idxSortColumn)," & vbLf & _
    "VSTACK(sort1,sort2,sort3))"
    

With rgSort.Offset(, 4).Resize(1, 1)
    .Formula2 = sortFormula

    rgSort.Value = .SpillingToRange.Value
    
    .Clear
End With
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Sort From To Rows

[image]

```
Sub SortFromToRows()

    Dim RowsFrom() As Variant: RowsFrom = Array(1, 701, 51)
    Dim RowsTo() As Variant: RowsTo = Array(50, 720, 700)
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = Application.Max(RowsTo)
    
    Dim rData() As Variant: ReDim rData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim n As Long, c As Long, r As Long
    
    For n = LBound(RowsTo) To UBound(RowsTo)
        For r = RowsFrom(n) To RowsTo(n)
            c = c + 1
            rData(r, 1) = c
        Next r
    Next n
        
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A4:AA4").Resize(rCount)
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = rg.Columns("X") ' or 24
    crg.Value = rData
        
    rg.Sort crg, xlAscending, , , , , , xlNo
    
    crg.ClearContents
    
End Sub
```